# Hide the line chart inside the Highstocks Scrollbar

Tags: angular, highcharts

I have requirement wherein I need to hide the chart inside the HighStock Scrollbar in my angular 6 app.

[image: ScrollBar with Line Chart]

I have gone through the docs [here](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/scrollbar) but none of the options suits me for my particular case.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is it enought for you to just hide it in CSS? .highcharts-navigator-series {
    display: none;
}
http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ejvtxdny/

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I needed to hide the line chart inside the navigator, not the complete navigation functionality. Hence `navigator{enabled:false}` wasn't what I was looking for. I found a workaround solution to hide the chart, pls refer my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to hide the line chart inside the navigator, not the complete navigation functionality. Hence `navigator{enabled:false}` wasn't what I was looking for.
Below work around did the job for me:

```
navigator: {
   series:{
      lineWidth:0,
      fillOpacity:0
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide only line plot, you can just simply do it in CSS:

```
.highcharts-navigator-series {
  display: none;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ejvtxdny)

If you want to hide whole navigator, you can set *navigator.enabled* property to false:

```
navigator: {
  enabled: false
},
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/8pyao3wd/)

[navigator.enabled](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator.enabled)

Answer (score 0):

That is the [`navigator`](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/navigator) series. You can disable it via:

```
navigator: {
    enabled: false
},
```